# MYSQL - INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (xxxx) WHERE column = 1;

Tags: mysql, sql

I've seen similar questions but not quite hitting it on the head.

I want to insert a value into a column, where a value in the column is equal to a certain value - ie 1.

So,

```
INSERT INTO table (columnName) VALUES (valueToAdd) WHERE id - 1;
```

This is what I THOUGHT it would be similar to, however no luck.

Thanks all!

Comment: It is not called insert but `UPDATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to insert a value into a column, where a value in the column is equal to a certain value - ie 1

It looks like you want `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE mytable SET columnName = valueToAdd WHERE id = 1;
```

`INSERT` creates new records. `UPDATE` modifies existing records.